# Slick slider: How to make slick slider as big as parent div with only CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css, slick.js

I have to set the height of the slick slider to fit the entire size of the header in which the slick slider is inside of. And I'm trying to only use CSS, because this slider is a pre-made component.

[Slick Slider Height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4vt9.jpg)

I only managed to stretch the image height wise but not over the whole width. I used following CSS:

```
.slick-slide img {
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
}
```

I tried many different ways to stretch it over the whole width of the page, but without success...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `vw` for width

`.slick-slide img { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }`

`vw` means viewport width while `vh` means viewport height

Comment: Yea thanks, I did use vw.
Made a typo while writing my question.
But changing the width doesn't affect the width of the whole slider somehow and I don't know why

Comment: Can you share your html, showing the image within the `slick-slide` class element

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to fix it. The issue was that the images were passed with a max-width set already.